# I want to display an array value based on the condition of another array value. What is the best way of doing this?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of users, but the users have different roles. One user can be an Admin.
I have a welcome message that will pop up when a user log in. The problem is that the system admin has access to all users and can switch between their accounts when doing support cases. This means that the welcome message would disaplay ALL user names when an admin logged in.

So I made a computed property that filters the list of current users, so that only the admin name gets shown, but now if a normal user logs in, no name will be shown.
Is there a way to make an if/else statement that tells the application: If current user is system admin, use the filtered property. If not, then just show the current user.

This is my code.

```
<template>
  <b-container>
      <b-modal
        centered
        v-model="isVisible">
          <b-row v-for="user in filterUser">
            <b-col class="text-center">
              <h2>{{ $t('welcomeTo') + ' ' }}<span style="color: #31a58e">website name</span> {{' ' + user.name }}</h2>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
      </b-modal>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

This my array and properties. I am actually getting the current user from axios, but for the sake of simplicity, I made a hardcoded array so it's easier to follow.

```
<script>
    data() {
      return {
        isVisible: true,
        currentUser: [
          {
            systemAdmin: true,
            name: 'Michael'
          },
          {
            systemAdmin: false,
            name: 'Marie'
          },
          {
            systemAdmin: false,
            name: 'Martin'
          }
        ],
        user: {},
      };
    },
    computed: {
      filterUser() {
        return this.currentUser.filter(user => user.systemAdmin)
      },
    }
</script>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
  filterUser() {
    if(this.currentUser.systemAdmin) {
      return this.currentUser.filter(user => user.systemAdmin)
    } else {
      return this.currentUser
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `filterUser` property is returning an array of users if the user is an admin, but a single user otherwise. Change `filterUser` so that in both cases it either returns an array or a single user object.

In this case, you expect to only have one admin user in the array, so you can use `currentUser.find` instead of `currentUser.filter` to return only the admin user.

```js
 filterUser() {
    if(this.currentUser.systemAdmin) {
      return this.currentUser.find(user => user.systemAdmin)
    } else {
      return this.currentUser
    }
  },
```

Now that `filterUser` is returning a single user, you can remove the `v-for` from `b-row` and display the single user's name:

```js
<b-row>
   <b-col class="text-center">
      <h2>{{ $t('welcomeTo') + ' ' }}<span style="color: #31a58e">website name</span> {{' ' + filterUser.name }}</h2>
   </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Comment: Just a small piece of feedback :-D, the `filterUser` property can be optimized like this- `return this.currentUser.systemAdmin ? this.currentUser.find(user => user.systemAdmin) : this.currentUser`